# Rails adding values to referenced table not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created the Database schema like the image below[image]

The prblem is I could not able to add data to my job_services table from the Job controller.

I try with the following code but It could not save the records into any table.

## Code

```
def create_job
@job = Job.new(
    job_code: user_params['job_code'],
    expect_comp_date: user_params['expected_completion_date'],
    actual_comp_date: user_params['actual_completion_date'],
    job_note: user_params['job_note']
)

@job.customer = Customer.find(user_params['customer_id'])

@service = Service.find(user_params['service_id'])
@jobservice = JobService.new(service_note: "Test Note", status: 'Test Status')
@job.jobservices.service  = @service


if @job.valid?
  if @job.save
    render :json => {"status" => 'S1000', "description" => 'Job Created'}
  end
else
  render :json => {"status" => 'E1000', "description" => @job.errors.messages}
end
end
```

## My Model Classes

```
//Job Model
class Job < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :jobservices
   belongs_to :customer
end

//Job Service Model
class JobService < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end

//Service Model
class Service < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: can you please add your model details?

Comment: I have updated the question please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **The associations you have taken and the naming conventions of rails are wrong in your question.**

2) **You have some syntax error and code changes in your controller, i,e you tried to create a job service before the job is created.**

**You can assign a jobservice to only a saved job.**

Here is the correct way to do them,

**Models:**

```
//Job Model

class Job < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :jobservices
   belongs_to :customer
end

//Job Service Model

class Jobservice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :service
end

//Service Model

class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :jobservices
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def create_job
    @job = Job.new(
        job_code: user_params['job_code'],
        expect_comp_date: user_params['expected_completion_date'],
        actual_comp_date: user_params['actual_completion_date'],
        job_note: user_params['job_note']
    )

    @job.customer = Customer.find(user_params['customer_id'])

    @service = Service.find(user_params['service_id'])

    if @job.valid?

      if @job.save

        @service = Service.find('3') 

        @jobservice = Jobservice.new(service: @service, service_note: "Test Note", status: 'Test Status')

        @job.jobservices << @jobservice


        render :json => {"status" => 'S1000', "description" => 'Job Created'}
      end
    else
      render :json => {"status" => 'E1000', "description" => @job.errors.messages}
    end
end
```

Comment: NameError (uninitialized constant Job::Jobservice):
  
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:31:in `create_job'

Comment: The 31st line is : `@job.jobservices.service  = @service `

Comment: `class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end`

Comment: instead of this change, `@jobservice.service  = @service`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129324/discussion-between-nifcody-and-sravan).